# Javascript: Multiple use of document.getElementById(id).appendChild()?

Tags: javascript, document, appendchild

Would using `document.getElementById(id).appendChild(img)` in the following code cause problems for the browser? I'm wondering if I use appendChild() to update an image many times during the lifetime of a document might create memory issues or would only one node be created?
I know that the following code only loads the image once but I was planning on expanding the code to randomly change the image as an animation. The document would see the call for
`document.getElementById(id).appendChild(img)` many times during the life of the document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var img = document.createElement("IMG");      
    images = new Array(); 

    function random_image(id) 
    {
        var i = 0;              

            for(i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
            {               
              images[i] = "image" + i + ".jpg"
            }       

        var random = (Math.floor(Math.random()*7)); 
        img.src = images[random];
        document.getElementById(id).appendChild(img);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "random_image('image')">
    <div id="image"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You do understand that each time you append something it will add another element, not replace the existing one?

Comment: Yup and thats the reason I asked this question because I wasn't too sure what would happen if I did use appendchild() many times over in the same document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing it as an animation, you're better off just changing the src of the image tag w/ the appropriate image url rather than replacing the image tag itself.

*** Edit in response to the first comment ***

You already have the code you need, but what you're doing is re-appending the image to the document every time.  What I'm suggesting is to just change the src of the image you've already got.

```
var img = document.createElement("IMG");      
images = new Array(); 
var i = 0;              
for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){               
    images[i] = "image" + i + ".jpg"
}  

function onLoad(){
    random_image('image');
    document.getElementById(id).appendChild(img);
}

function random_image(id){
    var random = (Math.floor(Math.random()*7)); 
    img.src = images[random];
}
window.onload = onLoad;
```

Note that I'm sort of assuming that the document load evnet isn't the only time you're calling the function. If it were, then your question is moot b/c you're asking about the impact of calling it a lot.  Doing it the way I'm showing, you first off get the code out of the document (a good thing) and also make it so that any calling code can replace the image file sourced by that one image tag.

Answer (score 1):

Not if you remove the image from the #image div with removeChild. When you remove the image from the document, garbage collection will quickly free up the memory. So, there is nothing to worry about, as long as you are not retaining the images hidden in the DOM somewhere.

A better idea would be to change the source of the existing img tag, which would replace the image without creating or destroying a new element.

Comment: "A better idea would be to change the source of the existing img tag" How would I code that, can you show an example please. thanks

Comment: Sure. Check the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/eaNTY/ . When you click on the image, it gets the image with getDocumentById, and then changes the src of the image with .src = "url of next image". You can do this as many times as you want to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it only one time it's ok

If doing it multiple times it'll add many images

Comment: No it won't; his current code isn't creating new image elements, just re-appending the one he already created.  It'll just move it to the end of the node he's creating it in each time he does that.  And possibly move the same image tag to a different location if he changes the input string to the function on subsequent calls.